# must be real number, not list

Tags: python, jinja2

I used almost every math. function but it didn't work at all so please help someone to solve this error.

```
@app.route('/property_grid')
    def property_grid():
        property = Properties.query.filter_by().all()
        last = math.ceil(property)/int(params['no_of_property']) <--error line-->
        page = request.args.get('page')
        if (not str(page).isnumeric()):
            page = 1
        property = Properties[(page-1)*int(params['no_of_property']):(page-1)*int(params['no_of_property'])+ int(params['no_of_property'])]
        page = int(page)
        if page==1:
            prev = "#"
            next = "/?page"+ str(page+1)
        elif page==last:
            prev = "/?page"+ str(page-1)
            next = "#"
        else:
            prev = "/?page"+ str(page-1)
            next = "/?page"+ str(page+1)
        return render_template('property_grid.html', params=params,property=property,prev=prev, next=next)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **full text** of the error and traceback.

Answer (score 1):

```
math.ceil(property)
```

looks like you're trying to compute the ceiling of a list.
You probably want

```
math.ceil(len(property))
```

to work with the *length* of the list.

However, in general you'll probably want something like

```
import math


def paginate(objects, page, per_page):
    n_pages = math.ceil(len(objects) / per_page)
    try:
        page = int(page)
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
    objects = objects[(page - 1) * per_page : page * per_page]
    prev = f"/?page={page - 1}"
    next = f"/?page={page + 1}"
    if page == 1:
        prev = "#"
    if page == n_pages:
        next = "#"
    return (objects, next, prev)


@app.route("/property_grid")
def property_grid():
    properties, next, prev = paginate(
        objects=Properties.query.filter_by().all(),
        page=request.args.get("page"),
        per_page=int(params.get("no_of_property", 15)),
    )
    return render_template(
        "property_grid.html", params=params, property=properties, prev=prev, next=next
    )
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to try and calculate the `ceil` of an int, which is what the `len` of anything will be...

Comment: @MattDMo Yeah, good point. Edited in a better example.